# How to Verify 'line break text' within 'textarea' present on Frame window using selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, dom, selenium-webdriver, textarea, richtextbox

I am automating webapplication using selenium webdriver and `C#. Now I am trapped in situation where I have to perform below steps:

1. Enter text in `Textarea` which is part of `frame`- This is single line text.
2. Then move mouse cursor to home and press `Shift+Enter`
3. Then one liner break get added into textarea which looks like attached images
4. Verify text with one liner break so text verification includes line break and `DOM` object looks like as below

   ```
   <html>
    <body>
     <br>
     This is single line text
    </body>
   </html>
   ```

As workaround I tried `By` Creating `Xpath` like this `//html/body`

It gives me text as :

`This is single line text but not able to verify there is line break or br tag also`

I am able switch to `frame` and able to get text from it but verification here should be like - `br` should be verified and if changed `xpath` to like this 
`//html/body/br` then it thorws `exception`

Any one has having any idea about how to verify line break within text area or how to verify text within `//iframe//html/body/br` text .

I have also tried to verify text from `Driver.pagesource` but then text within pagesource looks like below

```
\r\n\t    
<textarea id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ClientLetterRichTextBox\" 
name=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ClientLetterRichTextBox\"
 style=\"padding: 0px; width:600px; height: 330px;\" 
class=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ClientLetterRichTextBox_HtmlBox\">
This is a test of the Single Line break</textarea>\r\n\t</div>\r\n\t
```

[image]

Comment: Actually your question is not clear to me.. Do you want the text from textarea including `br` tag??

Comment: Or without `br` tag??

Comment: yes we can get text but can not get text with <br> tag. And i have to verify text with <br> tag

Comment: if(Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(.,'This is a test of the Single Line break')]")).displayed) .........is working for me but i have to check like this ......... .Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(.,'<br> This is a test of the Single Line break')]"));  any idea??

Comment: `br` is the html tag not string text, you need to first get text from the text area with `br` tag then verify...

Comment: i tried to get text from like -By.XPath("//html/body").gettext() and able to get it but i have to verify entered break line also including that text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122420/discussion-between-simond-and-saurabh-gaur).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `<br>` with text, You should try using `GetAttribute('innerHTML')`, it would return text with `HTML` tag inside an element as below :-

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("iframe id");

string innerHTML = Driver.FindElment(By.XPath("//html/body")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: Innerhtml returning text something like this -lass=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ClientLetterRichTextBox_HtmlBox\">This is a test of the Single Line break</textarea>\r\n\t</div>\r\n\t<div > but it not returning text with br tag

Comment: Then you need to locate through `textarea` instead of `body` and then use `.GetAttribute("innerHTML");`..

Comment: Actually `.GetAttribute("innerHTML")` returns all inner html inside located element, so if `textarea` also inside there, `.GetAttribute("innerHTML")` will return with `textarea` also,  so you need to located to the closest element that's why you could get only text with `br` tag..:)